# Pycharm, Robotframework not recognized

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, robotframework

with Pycharm i don't need to recognized Robotframework.
I installed python (3.12) and robotframework, selenium etc with pip.
[prerequisites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHW9v.png)

What am i missing?
[home_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLlXM.png)

With cmd robotframework run withoutproblem.
[cmd_run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSjtR.jpg)

My run/debug configuration [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw9hZ.png)

Upgrade 11/12/2023

With Pycharm 2023.3 I found run section! now, if I write " robot " in module there is this error when i press run: C:\Users...\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named robot.

what am I doing wrong?
picture:
[run/debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG4LT.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aohX.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your Run configuration setup.

The console window shows (see the very first line) that your robot script is passed directly to python.exe: `c:\Users\...\python.exe  C:\Users\...\test2.robot`. However, the Python interpreter doesn't know anything about Robot Framework.

Actually, the script should be passed to the robot module.
So, the whole run command could look like `C:\...\python.exe -m robot C:\...\test.robot`

Possible configuration:
[image: Possible configuration could be]

Comment: I understand you, thanks!
But my run/debug configuration don't have run (see picture in my main answer)
Have you any idea where edit then? 
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "don't have run"? Just in case, if you meant setting the `module` option, then it is accessible by clicking on the `Script path:` or the dropdown button right behind it. [Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#run-debug-parameters)

Comment: thanks Sam! With Pycharm 2023.3 I found run section! 
please can you read in my main question upgrade 11/12/2023?

Comment: Hmm, here's a draft guess below: 1. I see the Python.exe path is changed on the newest screenshot; it seems you have added a virtual environment.  Then, could you check if the Robotframework package is still available for the project?  Execute `pip list` in the Pycharm console and check if `robotframework` package is still available in the list.

Comment: The problem is pip list! is empy!
After i write pip install robotframework ecc... in console the problem is solved!
Thank you so much sam!